# Carve the text on an object and make it one piece

Tags: mesh, objects, text-object

I'm new to Blender. I have been trying to make the text (which I've already converted it to a Mesh) carved on the yellow plane and actually become the same piece, not separated.

[image]

In this picture, I joined the yellow plane and black text objects. Then in *Edit Mode*, I added the loop cuts, and moved an edge, it only moved the yellow plane and left the black text at its original position. I want the text to move together as the same piece. How do I achieve that?

I did try the *Boolean* and *Knife Project* methods, they seem to be one piece as I tried to move the vertex points or the faces of the text around, the mesh of the yellow plane follows along but I had problem in applying the *Loop Cut*. It will not cut through the plane and the text, but only cut at the top and bottom of the plane as shown in the image below.

[image]

I'm fine with whichever method as long as the result turns out that the text and the plane mesh actually unite and move together, and also allows me to apply the loop cuts normally.

Here are the Blender files for two versions:

[Knife Project Method](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1j41hZojHxi77OP7EXBC3EeLclYXGDf4B/view?usp=sharing) and
[Joined Objects Method](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HiqE8JEwbjxydElQSKoNB6waTyFvIL3C/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Loop Cut* will only work with quads, i.e. faces consisting of 4 edges and vertices. When you choose an edge where you want to start the loop cut, it continues over the opposite edge. This means a loop cut cannot be performed if the face has more or less than 4 edges because there is no distinct opposite face.

What you can do in *Edit Mode* is go into *Front Orthographic* view by pressing <kbd>Numpad 1</kbd>, then <kbd>K</kbd> for the *Knife Tool*, press <kbd>C</kbd> for *angle constraint* > *ON* and to make sure everything will be cut also press <kbd>Z</kbd> for *cut through* > *ON*.

Now move the knife to the top edge until a green square appears, left-click, go down to the bottom edge (the *angle constraint* option provides a straight vertical cut) until another green square appears and left-click again.

To confirm the single cut now press <kbd>Return</kbd>. Or instead, to prepare more cuts at once press <kbd>E</kbd>, then repeat the left-clicking like before on a different region of the edges. After you've selected all cuts hit <kbd>Return</kbd> to confirm.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed explanation @Gordon Brinkmann. It helped me a lot! Your answer is the solution.

Comment: @Juniorlearner At least that was a solution for cutting the mesh when loop cuts don't work. But you should also have a look at Chris' answer for projecting the text onto the plane, if you don't want to carve it into the mesh.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a more "dynamic" solution i would try the shrinkwrap modifier:

1. Add a plane with some loopcuts:

[image]

2. add a text

[image]

3. add a shrinkwrap modifier like this:

[image]

4. if you now move your text on the x axis you can get this:

[image]

5. and of course you can change the shape of your plane and the text will follow your changes:

[image]

The advantage of this solution is:

- you can change your text - it still works
- you can change the form of the plane - still works

Comment: Thank you very much for suggesting this dynamic solution. I like the flexibility this method offers.

Comment: you are welcome

Comment: When I tried to move the edge up/down, or shorten the plane vertically, it looks like the text won't shrink along. Do you have any idea how to fix that?

Comment: the shrinkwrap modifier as i used it in this example does only work in one direction (x). Thats why moving the edge up and down (z-axis) won't work.